# move_uploaded_file PHP method not working

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, backend

I'm trying to write the server side code of a file uploading page. On the client side i used jQuery AJAX object to send the FormData object which contains two images with the keys "0" and "1". I checked that the object is sent to the backend.

The only problem is that the move_uploaded_file method returns false.

```
if (isset($_FILES["0"])) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["0"]['tmp_name'], "/" . $_FILES["0"]["name"])){
        echo "okay";
    }
    else {
        echo "halfokay";
        print_r($_FILES);
    }
}
else {
    exit;   
}
```

The output:

```
halfokArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => _DSC0726.JPG
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => _DSC0728.JPG
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

UPDATE: it works with a smaller image, but in the end it is not there where it should be.

The JQuery:

```
      var formData = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i < window.images.length; i++) {
                formData.append(i,window.images[i]);
              }
                  $.ajax({
                    url: 'realpetadupload.php',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data){
                      alert(data);
                    }
                  });
```

Comment: well, theoretically i can that's what the FormData object is for

Comment: BTW, `1` means `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` anyway.

Comment: Show the form + jquery plz

Answer (score 0):

In your output error is showing 1. That means the uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Please check size of file uploaded. Its exceeding max file size allowed to upload.

Comment: yeah, with a smaller image it returns true, but the moved file is not there where it should be

Comment: Please check if destination path is correct and writable.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that for some reason i can't write to my root folder of the web-server. Changing the path to somewhere else is the solution.